# Can't figure out why my angular code is not working with Ionic framework and Intel XDK

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I've created a Ionic project in Intel XDK, I started setting up my navigation bar with buttons, I added a status button which will cycle and change the label from available, away and busy when the button is clicked.

I started out small and wanted to insert a string through a scope variable I defined in my JavaScript app.js. I can't seem to get it working. app.js is defined in my head tags and I ng-app inside my div where my button lives. I feel as if the angular.js bundled in ionic is not working for some reason, Here's a section of my code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="xhr.js"></script>
<script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="marginal/marginal-position.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_init_services.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_uib_w_8_popover.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_uib_w_10_popover.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/sidebar.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/swipe.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/init-app.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="popup/popup.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/hammer.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/swipe-hammer.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_uib_w_13_popup.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/ad/ionic_subpage.js"></script>
```

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="upage" id="mainpage">
  <div class="upage-outer content-area vertical-col left fixed-header-footer">
    <div id="page_28_32" class="upage-content vertical-col left ">
      <template class="uib-ionic-popup widget uib_w_13 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/popup" data-ver="0"></template>

    </div>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar inner-element uib_w_1 bar-balanced bar-header" data-uib="ionic/header" data-ver="0" align-title="center">
      <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col">
        <button class="button widget uib_w_2 ion d-margins button-clear ion-android-more icon-right" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0"></button>
<div class="upage" id="mainpage">
  <div class="upage-outer content-area vertical-col left fixed-header-footer">
    <div id="page_28_32" class="upage-content vertical-col left ">
      <template class="uib-ionic-popup widget uib_w_13 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/popup" data-ver="0"></template>

    </div>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar inner-element uib_w_1 bar-balanced bar-header" data-uib="ionic/header" data-ver="0" align-title="center">
      <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col">
        <button class="button widget uib_w_2 ion d-margins button-clear ion-android-more icon-right" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0"></button>
      </div>

<h1 class="title">Medroid</h1>
      <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col">
        <button class="button widget uib_w_7 ion ion-android-reminder icon-right d-margins" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" id="notifications"></button>
        <button class="button widget uib_w_6 ion d-margins ion-android-forums icon-right" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" id="inbox" ng-controller="uib_w_8_popover_controller" ng-click="show($event)"></button>
        <button  ng-app="statusButton" class="button widget uib_w_5 ion d-margins button-large ion-android-data icon-left" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" ng-controller="statusCtrl" id="status">{{status}}</button>
      </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('statusButton',['ionic'])
.controller('statusCtrl', function($scope){ 
$scope.status = "hey";
}
});
```

[Here's the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0wae.jpg)

Update: I tried several times to get angular controllers to work with no avail, I simply cannot get angular working with this IDE.

Comment: I spent a couple more hours, I created a new project, I tried just doing another angular module and I still cannot get it working. I might just give up on ionic and angular and write it using jquery.

Comment: have you setup ng-app, or are you using any script minification tool ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you A.T. I'm unsure what a tool you're referring too

Comment: can you show the *entire* HTML page? this snippet doesn't show what scripts you are loading, in what order you are loading them in, or where you are loading the module/controller.

Comment: also, I'm not sure that you can add `ng-app` to a `button` input element.

Comment: I've tried a fresh project which a controller, and inserted a expression in the HTML that is referenced by the scope variable, the ng-app directive was set in the body tag, I tried moving around the ng-controller to different tags to see what would happen. Yet I still can't get the variable to show in the view. I'm running my XDK on linux and I made sure all the file permissions are good just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, It appears that angular doesn't work when you use the design view with ionic. I ended up creating a new blank project with app designer disabled and did everything from scratch and it works. If anyone else is having this issue with app designer let me know.